# select latest answer and also nos of attempt?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on quiz app. One of my table `attempts` is:

```
id   qid   answer
--   ---   ------
 1    42   hello
 2     7   magic
 3    42   ni hao
 4    42   ciao
 5     1   foo
 6    42   ohayo
```

I need latest answer on the question no 42 (`qid=42`), and also the number of time attempts on this question. I've try:

```
SELECT answer, count(*) FROM attempts WHERE qid=42 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Then I just realize that `ORDER BY` execute after `count(*)`, so my query here gives answer of first attempt, not latest.

My workaround is to split this into 2 query:

```
SELECT answer   FROM attempts WHERE qid=42 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT count(*) FROM attempts WHERE qid=42;
```

I wonder if this can be combine into 1 query?

Comment: You are trying to select two different things, so I would say no, you cannot. And it is probably clearer that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you 1 result per qid w/ the number of attempts as well as the answer associated w/ the first attempt.

```
SELECT A.qid, answer as FirstAnswer, B.Attempts 
FROM attempts A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
    qid,
    COUNT(*) over(Partition by qid) as NumberAttempts,
    MIN(id) over(partition by qid) as First_AnswerID
    from attempts) B ON A.id = B.First_AnswerID
```

OR....

```
SELECT A.qid, A.answer as FirstAnswer, B.NumAtmps, C.FirstID FROM attempts A
INNER JOIN (SELECT qid, count(*) as NumAtmps FROM attempts group by qid) B ON A.qid = B.qid 
INNER JOIN (SELECT qid, min(id) as FirstID FROM attempts group by qid) C ON A.qid = C.qid AND A.id = C.FirstID
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't state that my database engine is MySQL.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with MySQL, sorry...but could you do something like....   SELECT A.qid, A.answer as FirstAnswer, B.NumAtmps, C.FirstID FROM attempts A INNER JOIN (SELECT qid, count(*) as NumAtmps group by qid) B ON A.qid = B.qid INNER JOIN (SELECT qid, min(id) as FirstID FROM attempts group by qid) C ON A.qid = C.qid AND A.id = C.FirstID

Comment: so much join... i still wonder if there exists simpler version (less join, or just where), it working perfectly however.